# scala is inferring Nothing though defining with explicit types

Tags: scala, type-inference

In the following code I'm getting error

```
Error:(48, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Map[Int,Option[List[Int]]])
 required: (Int, Nothing)
          f



 def tuplesWithRestrictions1(): (Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]]) = {
    val df = new DecimalFormat("#")
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0)
    val result = ((0 until 1000) foldLeft ((0, Map.empty(Int, Some(List.empty[Int]))))) {
      (r: (Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]]), x: Int) => {
        val str = df.format(x).toCharArray
        if (str.contains('7')) {
          import scala.math._
          val v = floor(log(x)) - 1
          val v1 = (pow(10, v)).toInt
          val m = (r._2).get(v1) {
            case None => r._2 + (v1 -> List(x))
            case Some(xs: List[Int]) => r._2 updated(x, xs :+ x)
          }
          val f = (r._1 + 1, m)
          f
        } else r
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

Why the compiler is inferring Nothing though I'm explicitly specifying that result is of (Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]]) type ? and How to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `Map.empty(Int, Some(List.empty[Int]))`, probably you intended to use `Map.empty[Int, Option[List[Int]]]`

Comment: Yes you are correct thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `val m = (r._2).get(v1)` returns `Option[Option[List[Int]]]`. I think, you should do pattern matching inside pattern matching to get results you want.